# Send Requests to a cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

How to send requests to the Google cloud function which has authentication enabled.

So far the solutions I have tried are:

1. I have tried calling the cloud function from the local system using node.js code. Below is the code.

```
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const auth = new GoogleAuth();

async function request() {
  var url = 'https://us-central1-PROJECT_NAME.cloudfunctions.net/testrequests';
  var targetAudience = url;

  console.info(`request ${url} with target audience ${targetAudience}`);
  const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience);
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.info(res.data);
}

request().catch(err => {
  console.error(err.message);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

The above solution is picked up from: [Google docs link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#functions-bearer-token-example-nodejs)

I got error saying:

> Could not fetch ID token: request to http://IP_ADDRESS/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?format=full&audience=https://us-central1-PROJECT_NAME.cloudfunctions.net/testrequests failed, reason: socket hang up

My cloud functions have this code written in it:

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.http('helloHttp', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello ${req.query.name || req.body.name || 'World'}!`);
});
```

Can Anyone help me solve this problem or give an alternative solution. Thank you!

Comment: Did you first run `gcloud auth application-default login` before running the code on your local system? The Google client libraries are searching for credentials and the last one to be checked is the metadata server. Your system will not have a metadata server except if you downloaded and installed one. Read this [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc) on how to setup credentials on your development system.